# 2001 Honda Accord Fuel Line Parts

Tags: honda, fuel-system, accord, fuel-line

I'm replacing my leaky, rusty fuel line on my 2001 Honda Accord LX.  I'll be using 5/16" copper nickel tubing.  I'm looking for fittings to attach to the OEM rear quick connect supply and return tubes and to the supply line threaded fitting at the top of the firewall.  Here are pics of the parts, but I'd like to know the specs that would fit my car, (e.g. -6AN or -8AN?) or maybe identify a part number for the fitting? Thanks.

[image]
[image]